# Load non-SSL dynamic page(jps) which make requests on iframe on SSL website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ssl

I have website with SSL certificate.
I want to get and show to users url without ssl (train schedules) from Bulgarian State Railways which doesn't have SSL connection. While my site does not use SSL I showed the schedules through iframe with src='http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/mobile/guide.jsp', but now this feature doesn't work for understandable reasons.

Bulgarian State Railways also offer information from the electronic boards of the larger stations. For that feature I create php file and get all content from url and put the file url as iframe src

For example:

```
iframe src="./eltabla-sofia.php"

<?php $elTabla = file_get_contents('http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/mobile/lists.jsp?st=SOFIA'); echo $elTabla; ?>
```

Also I get the css files and it is work and look great (I changed the original css with mine), because the content is loaded once and doesn't have further requests, but on the train schedules user need to type from station and to station to get today schedules.

How can I show this non-ssl page which make request to my ssl website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Becquerel's idea here is my realisation. The approach work for now without autocomplete, but will be added list of stations soon:

form.html

```
<form id="form_51888" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="razpisanie.php">
        <div class="form_description">
            <h1>Моля въведете начална и крайна гара на латиница.</h1>
            <h1>Например: sofia,plovdiv,varna</h1>
        </div>                      
        <ul >
            <li id="li_1" >
                <div>
                    <input id="fromStation" name="fromStation" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="НАЧАЛНА ГАРА" value=""/> 
                </div> 
            </li>       
            <li id="li_2" >
                <div>
                    <input id="toStation" name="toStation" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="КРАЙНА ГАРА" value=""/> 
                </div> 
            </li>

            <li class="buttons">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="51888" />                    
                    <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Търсене" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

and php code of razpisanie.php

```
<?php

    $fromStation = $_POST['fromStation']; // this should be sanitized and validated first
    $toStation = $_POST['toStation'];

    $SanfromStation = filter_var($fromStation, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $SantoStation = filter_var($toStation, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ((isset($SanfromStation) && !empty($SanfromStation)) && (isset($SantoStation) && !empty($SantoStation))){
        $content = file_get_contents("http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/mobile/search.jsp?fromstation={$SanfromStation}&tostation={$SantoStation}");

        $contentEnc = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $content);

        echo $contentEnc;
    }
    else echo 'There is an error';

    ?>
```

Thank you again Becquerel!

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not easily doable, as modern browsers will block non-HTTPS requests if you are on https website.

I think your best option would be to create your own form, with `fromStation` and `toStation` fields, collect this information from user yourself on your website, and then hit the railways website similar way you are doing, but instead of hardcoded URLs, there would be variables provided by the user

```
$fromStation = $_GET['fromStation']; // this should be sanitized and validated first
$toStation = $_GET['toStation'];

$content = file_get_contents("http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/mobile/search.jsp?fromstation={$fromStation}&tostation={$toStation}");
echo $content;
```

This is just a very simple prototype, and you will lose stuff like autocomplete (unless you write it yourself). But unless the Bulgarian railways move their website on https, I am afraid you don't have too many options.